# How to Keep Entity Framework Code First from using Derived Classes that Aren't Part of the Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Here is a generic example of what I'm doing, what is happening, and what SHOULD be happening:

First, I declare my code first model, something like this:

Context:

```
namespace Models {
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ClassA> ClassA { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ClassB> ClassB { get; set; }

        public MyContext()
            : base("name=MyContext")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Classes A and B:

```
namespace Models {
    public class ClassA
    {
        public int ClassAID { get; set; }
        public string BaseAVal { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClassB> ClassBChildren {get; set; }//Relation Property
    }
    public class ClassB
    {
        public int ClassBID { get; set; }
        public int ClassAID { get; set; }//Foreign Key
        public string BaseBVal { get; set; }
        public virtual ClassA ClassAParent { get; set; }//Relation Property
    }
}
```

Now elsewhere, in another namespace, I have classes for a different purpose that derive from the model classes.

Derived Classes:

```
namespace CalculatedModels {
    public class DerivedClassA : ClassA
    {
        string SecondAVal { get; set; }
        public static DerivedClassA fromDBItem(ClassA dbItem) {
            //Create a DerivedClassA
            //Copy over inherited properties from dbItem (via Reflection)
            //Calculate its non-inherited properties
            //return it
        }
        public ClassA toDBItem() {
            //Create a ClassA
            //Copy over inherited properties from this (via Reflection)
            //return it
        }
    }
    public class DerivedClassB : ClassB
    {
        string SecondBVal { get; set; }
        //Conversion functions similar to those in DerivedClassA go here...
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I have EntityFramework generate the database from this model. I DON'T want it to include ANYTHING from the derived classes. They are NOT for the database to concern itself with! Why else would I put them in a completely different namespace and make the collections in the context be of the non-extended base types? Tables SHOULD look like this:

```
Table: ClassA
    ---Columns---
    ClassAID (PrimaryKey, int, not null)
    BaseAVal (nvarchar(max), null)

Table: ClassB
    ---Columns---
    ClassBID (PrimaryKey, int, not null)
    ClassAID (ForeignKey, int, not null)
    BaseBVal (nvarchar(max), null)
```

But EF insists on ruining my intended schema by adding the newly declared properties of the the derived classes like so:

```
Table: ClassA
    ---Columns---
    ClassAID (PrimaryKey, int, not null)
    BaseAVal (nvarchar(max), null)
    SecondAVal (nvarchar(max), null) --This should NOT be here!!
    Discriminator (nvarchar(128)) --Neither should this!!

Table: ClassB
    ---Columns---
    ClassBID (PrimaryKey, int, not null)
    ClassAID (ForeignKey, int, not null)
    BaseBVal (nvarchar(max), null)
    SecondBVal (nvarchar(max), null) --This should NOT be here!!
    Discriminator (nvarchar(128)) --Neither should this!!
```

As you can see, it is including the derived classes as a possible part of the model and/or database system, despite NOTHING in the model having ANYTHING to do with them. THEY reference stuff in the model, NOT the other way around--EVER. I DON'T want it to use them! How do I keep it from doing this?

Comment: Have you considered using composition rather than inheritance?

Comment: You can add NotMapped properties, instead of creating a new class:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity framework is doing what it should do here as your setup follows the Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) Inheritance pattern.

**Discriminator** is added so that database can distinguish when a ClassA or a DervivedClassA is added to the DB

You can stop EF mapping your Derived classes using NotMapped attribute.
add the following namespace

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

DerivedClassB

```
[NotMapped]
public class DerivedClassB : ClassB
{
    string SecondBVal { get; set; }
    //Conversion functions similar to those in DerivedClassA go here...
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I wanted. The only problem left is that it isn't COMPLETELY ignoring the derived classes. When I try to give them the same name (diff namespace still) EF complains about them having the same simple name. I AM using EF 6.x, for which they SAY that error was fixed. I guess that claim is false.

Comment: That cleans the DB but now I can't insert the derived class objects into the DB

Comment: I added the [NotMapped] attribute to my "DerivedClassB", but I still get the error:
Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'MyNamespace.DerivedClassB'. :-(